# How to change toolbar color

Tags: android, toolbar

I've been searching how to customize the toolbar, for example how to add background color, but I don't understand how it works.

I've been trying to add a custom style for my toolbar but any result ...

The Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design">
```

The style.xml file

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Design" parent="Base.Theme.Design">
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.Design" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>    
    ...
```

And the toolbar in layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Answer (score 27):

Thanks, but any solution works.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

or

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
```

May be because my toolbar is in android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (to put a android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) ?

Answer (score 8):

In fact, there was a [Android Developers pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/AV2ooBWY1iy) which go into details on how to color the Toolbar using `colorPrimary`.

You were definitely on the right track, adding `colorPrimary` to your theme. What you need is to set the background on the Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Note, if you have a dark `colorPrimary` and a light theme, you'll need to also add `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` to ensure the text and icons are white over the dark background.

Comment: but how can i do it dynamically as i am using common toolbar throughout the app and sometimes we want different style, especially gradient background to the same toolbar somewhere, that should also allow me to change font style of toolbar title or for the textview that is under that toolbar?!

Answer (score 5):

set Color from resource file

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>
```

in your styles. It's the same tag name with window background, but changes the toolbar background color only when you use it with your toolbar styles.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor((Color.parseColor("#80000000")));
```

Comment: Thank you, but it don't work. May be because i'm in a CoordinatorLayout ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background in the xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it don't work. May be because i'm in a CoordinatorLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is put in your styles.xml :

```
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Like in my folder :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/asap</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

</style>
```