# Toolbar Text Color not change

Tags: java, android

I use a toolbar and when scrolling the image it shows with text,
I try in java also `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);` But it does not work the text color always white

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/buttontext"
            app:popupTheme="@style/appBarTheme" />
```

Comment: this link could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237284/how-to-change-toolbar-color

Comment: `textColorSecondary` will help you. Additionally also please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070040/textcolor-vs-textcolorprimary-vs-textcolorsecondary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to style.xml

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And Make your Widget.Toolbal like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  />
```

You can change the color in `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>` to whatever color you want.